# Unnamed objects whose lifetime is bound to a block of code?

Tags: c++, lifetime, raii

The question is pretty simple: On occasion I encounter situations in which I modify some (rather global) state, for example a log level — to preempt bitching about global states: Not my framework, nothing I can do about it ;-).

In order to be nice I should restore the old state after I'm done, so I save it and at the end restore it. This is an obvious case for RAII:

```
// Some header
/// A RAII class which records a state and restores it upon destruction.
struct StateRestorer
{
    State oldState;
    StateRestorer(State oldStateArg) : oldState(oldStateArg) {}
    ~StateRestorer() { setState(oldState); }
};


// Happens a couple times somewhere in my program
{
    StateRestorer oldStateRestorer(getState());
    State newState(/* whatever */);
    setState(newState);
    // Do actually useful things during the new state
    
    // oldStateRestorer goes out of scope and restores the old state.
}
```

Now, I don't actually *need* the `oldStateRestorer` variable. Don't get me wrong, I *do* need the object it refers to; but I never access `oldStateRestorer` in any way. The need to have a name for it is mildly cumbersome. If I were alone I might call it `s` but I'm a strong proponent of good naming so that people to whom the program is unfamiliar (likely me in two years) can readily understand it. On occasion these state variations are nested so that I have to invent new names lest my compiler warns me that I'm shadowing another variable (which in other cases is a serious warning, and I don't like warnings to begin with and now I'm all upset). As I said, mildly annoying.

The question boils down to this:

**Is there a way to have an unnamed object whose lifetime is a block of code in C++?**

(If somebody felt compelled to give an example in their favorite different language I wouldn't mind though.)

Comment: FWIW, all unnamed objects have automatic storage duration.  I think you mean to ask if there is a way to create a scope persistent unnamed object.  AFAIK, the answer to that is no.  You could hide it behind a macro like `CREATE_RESTORER(getState());` and have the macro hide the variable declaration.  You can leverage `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` with that to create unique "unnamed" objects.

Comment: @NathanOliver Oh, true. Somehow I thought that a temporary object has a fourth, separate storage class but ... probably not ... hm.

Comment: I always use `_` as my unnamed object's name.  Since there's frequently only one in a code block.  It's hard to get it past code reviewers though ...

Comment: @davidbak Problem with that is that `_` is widely defined as a macro to use `gettext` library.

Comment: @eerorika - oh, well, if your choice is between a convenient-to-type easy-to-read convention like `_` for RAII objects, or using some, uh, random crufty library .... I know which way _I'm_ going!  (Although frequently there should be no conflict as RAII objects like scopeguards and such are usually pretty tightly scoped ... just don't use one in the same scope as gettext ...) (TBH, I just looked at the gettext FAQ and it contained a gratuituous, annoying, and unprofessional reference to Win32 so it's unlikely I'll be bothering with it myself...)

Comment: @eerorika - plus ... wait a minute! - defining `_` as a _macro_ in a header?? What kind of code does that?  That's worse than `min` and `max` in `windef.h` and that guy who wrote the FAQ has the gall to throw bricks at Windows?  Never mind my comment about scope above - doesn't apply with junk headers like that obviously ...

Comment: @davidbak I suppose "random crufty library" is a way to describe *the* most widely used i18n library used in ~20 different programming languages. Yeah, GNU documentation can sometimes be a bit cringey. The original Solaris library may have had more professional documentation (or maybe it was like that from the start). I would recommend against defining _ macro in a header. The library itself doesn't define it. It is conventionally defined by the programs that use it.

Comment: @eerorika - the crufty bit was a joke.  and I didn't realize that the header doesn't define it ... okay then! Just don't use it in the same scope as your raii scope guard and it all plays together nicely!

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to have an unnamed object with automatic storage duration in C++?

Technically no. However, temporary objects are pretty much similar: They are unnamed and are destroyed automatically. Furthermore, lifetime of a temporary object can be expended by binding a reference to it:

```
struct silly_example {
    T&& ref;
}

int main()
{
    silly_example has_automatic_storage {
         .ref = T{}; // temporary object
    };
}
```

In this example, we have a named object with automatic storage which refers to a(n unnamed) temporary object whose lifetime matches that of the automatic object.

I don't think this would be useful for the case that you describe.

---

Note that this is a typical issue with this kind of RAII types. An example within the standard library is `std::lock_guard`:

```
std::mutex some_mutex;

{
    const std::lock_guard<std::mutex>
        must_have_a_name(some_mutex);
    
    // critical section which won't refer to the guard
}
```

Worst part is not that you must come up with a name, but that `const std::lock_guard<std::mutex> (some_mutex);` is a valid function decalaration and will compile succesfully without creating the guard.

---

> (If somebody felt compelled to give an example in their favorite different language I wouldn't mind though.)

Python is particularly elegant. Since it doesn't have destructors, it cannot have RAII types like this in the first place.

```
some_mutex = Lock()

with some_mutex:
    # critical section here
```

A class that can be used with `with` uses normal functions (with particular names) rather than constructor and destructor:

```
class WithExample: 
    def __init__(self, args): 
        pass
      
    def __enter__(self):
        # resource init
        # may return something to be used within the scope
        pass
  
    def __exit__(self): 
        # reource release
        pass
```

Comment: I also thought of another indirection -- one could even create a unique pointer. But that only moves the issue a level up, doesn't it?

Comment: Good to know I'm not alone. Your last paragraph is the most vexing parse, right? That works even though `std::lock_guard<>` is a visible type name?

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Technically not the "Most Vexing Parse" as that is slightly more vexing :) But the issue is the same

Comment: An example of Most Vexing Parse would be `std::lock_guard<std::mutex> must_have_a_name(std::mutex());`. Passing a temporary mutex makes no sense, so this would be broken even if it wasn't a function declaration.

Comment: This is what grates my cheese. If it were a function return, you could decorate it with [[nodiscard]] to at least get a compile error out of it.  But if it's an RAII constructor, there's no way to get a complaint about it creating an unnamed object.  And therefore destruct at the end of the statement instead of the end of the block.

Answer (score 3):

If macros and at least C++17 are on the table, you can get by with the fairly simple:

```
// Standard issue concatenation macros
#define CONCAT(A, B) CONCAT_(A, B)
#define CONCAT_(A, B) A##B


#define WITH(...) if([[maybe_unused]] auto CONCAT(_dO_nOt_tOuCh, __LINE__)(__VA_ARGS__); true)
```

The `if` with init statement, and guaranteed copy elision, is what calls for C++17. The first feature is obvious, but the second is useful since it allows for non-copyable and non-movable types as RAII types.

With that macro in hand, one can simply write

```
WITH(StateRestorer(getState())) {
  //Your code here.
}
```

Now, at this point I'm certain the question of multiple RAII objects rises. And one probably thinks we must either do a lot of nesting, or get the warning again if we instead opt to write the rather ugly

```
WITH(A) WITH(B) WITH(C) {

}
```

And we *can* solve it. Either by doing as we did, but using the GNU specific `__COUNTER__` macro instead of `__LINE__`. Or by employing more C++17 to let `WITH` accepts a comma seperated list of RAII expressions. Under the reasonable assumption that RAII types are always classes, we can do the following

```
namespace detail {
    template<class... Ts>
    struct glue : Ts... {};

    template<class... Ts>
    glue(Ts...) -> glue<Ts...>;
}
#define WITH(...) if([[maybe_unused]] detail::glue CONCAT(_dO_nOt_tOuCh, __LINE__){__VA_ARGS__}; true)
```

It uses CTAD to generate a type inheriting from a comma seperated list of RAII types on the spot (and in the very likely case all the expressions are prvalues, initializes the bases directly). With it, we may write

```
WITH(StateRestorer1(...), StateRestorer2(...)) {
}
```

The destructors will of course be called in reverse order to the comma seperated list.

---

As an aside, this annoyance was part of the motivation behind [P0577 (Keep That Temporary!)](https://wg21.link/P0577). There were some interesting ideas in the paper, but sadly it did not gain traction.

Comment: `_dO_nOt_tOuCh` breaks with the nested scopes and shadowing warnings that were the issue for OP in the first place.

Comment: @eerorika - Nested scopes won't break the RAII. The warning itself is silly anyway. But if one is burdened with it, they may as well use a macro to generate the variable name.

Comment: Interesting reference to the paper! The mutex use has basically the same problem as my state (don't need a name).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think what you want can be done in C++ directly.

However, if your issue is giving names to objects, you can consider to call a function instead. You don't have to give names to function calls:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename RAII,typename...Args>
auto with(Args...args){
    return [=](auto f){
        RAII boring_name{args...};
        f();    
    };
}

struct foo { 
    int state;
    foo(int state) : state(state){}
    ~foo(){ std::cout << "bye " << state << "\n";} 
};

int main() {
   with<foo>(42)(
       [&](){
           std::cout << "hello\n";
           with<foo>(123)(
               [&](){
                   std::cout << "hello nested\n";
               }
           );
       }
   );    
}
```

[Output](https://godbolt.org/z/dP6EW9)

```
hello
hello nested
bye 123
bye 42
```

Comment: I have never used lambdas (and the compiler at work is pre-C++11), so forgive my ignorance: The actual user code is all in the with() call (e.g. printing hello)?

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica yep, sorry i should have explained better. `foo` is the analogon to your `StateRestorer`. I have to admit that I don't know what is the right way to forward the arguments to its constructor so I just made a copy. Actual user code is the two `std::cout`s. From the top of my head I don't know how to do it pre-C++11, as written in my answer it needs c++14 I believe.

Comment: Well, it's fascinating. Doesn't look easier than inventing a name, necessarily, but still.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica well, its more a curiosity rather than actually useful when the aim is clean code. I read "global state" and thought woohoo anything goes :P.